# First-person grammatical changes in tefillah

Tags: halacha, tefilla, women, grammar-dikduk

Someone mentioned to me the idea that women should be saying "Modah ani" in the morning instead of "Modeh ani," which, grammatically speaking, makes sense. I've never seen any siddur that makes that change - even the Artscroll women's siddur uses the nikkud "Modeh ani." Are there sources in halachah that discuss the change to feminine in first-person references in tefillah when women are davening?

Comment: The particular example is pretty weak since מודה אני isn't really a formal part of prayer with a fixed text, and the change doesn't affect consonants so it's hard to prove from written texts that people weren't making that change a long time ago.

Comment: I had the same question regarding birchas hamazon and other places where I would say "אותי ואת אשתי", should I skip the "אשתי" part if I'm not married?

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair point - still, it's interesting that a women's siddur published by Artscroll, which prides itself on its scholarship and accuracy, doesn't make the change.

Comment: @Yehuda My Rav doesn't like that siddur for that exact reason.

Comment: @Yehuda I have never heard anyone say Artscroll prides itself on its scholarship and accuracy

Comment: @DoubleAA It's in the introductions of the Hebrew-English Artscroll siddurim, you can read how they describe their process of creating and editing the siddur.

Comment: @Yehuda They certainly had a creation process (every book does), I've just never heard anyone say Artscroll prides itself on its scholarship and accuracy. Indeed I've heard many people say their works lack in scholarship and accuracy.

Comment: The sfas emes rodelhiem siddur says modah ani for woman